# Net water pressure in pipes

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Greeting, I have two pipes A ,B same diameter, joined to be one pipe C with double diameter of A ,  water flow in A with pressure 90bar and in B with pressure 40 bar    . 
The question is how much will be the water pressure in pipe c ? 
Regards

Comment: This question needs a diagram for proper explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Pressure will be 90 bar. Also, you will get reverse flow in pipe B because the pressure is greater. The water in B will not add to the overall pressure of the source.

Consider A and B are connected to tanks with water level deep enough to make 90 and 40 bar pressure. Tank A will fill tank B until the level is nearly identical then both will contribute equal pressure to C and have near equal flow rates.

Answer (score 0):

I think we don't have enough information to solve this problem.
Are the given pressure values hydrostatic or hydrodynamic?
Hydrostatic would basically mean the height of the water level, e.g. $90\mbox{bar} \hat{=} 900\mbox{m}$, hydrodynamic is the difference of static pressure and pressure losses.

For a hydraulic system like this we can make some assumptions *at the intersection*:

- **flow continuity:** $Q_A+Q_B+Q_C=0$

This holds true, as water is almost incompressible, thus all that comes in must come out somewhere.

- **energy equilibrium:** $H_A=H_B=H_C$

At the intersection the hydraulic head of all three flows must be equal.
In this case $H=\frac{p}{\rho g}+\frac{2Q^2}{\pi D g}$ 
The pressures may indeed vary, but two pressure values do not suffice to calculate the third value.